# python program error elif else if

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def Game():

    # Story Background
    print "You decide to take a walk outside one night when you come accross a corn field."
    print "You notice an omnious sound coming from the other side of the maze."
    Enter = raw_input("Do you enter? (yes or no)")

    if Enter == "Yes" or "yes":
        print "You walk into the maze and the corn is so thick together you cant push through"
        print "so you walk down the isle surrounded by corn and you come to an intersection."
        turn = raw_input("Which way do you go? (Left, Right, Forward, Leave)")

        if turn == "Left" or "left":
            print "After you turn left you come accross a dead end and you are forced to turn around."
            print "You return to the intersection."
            turn2 = raw_input("Which way do you go? (Left, Forward, Leave)")

            if turn2 == "Forward" or "forward":
                print "you walk on deeper into the maze when you come to a left turn"
                print "you turn left and come accross a crossroad."
                turn3 = raw_input("Which way do you go? (Left, Right, Leave)")

                if turn3 == "Right" or "right":
                    print "You come to a dead end and are forced to turn around"
                    turn4 = raw_input("Which way do you go? (Forward, Leave)")

                    if turn4 == "Forward" or "forward":
                        print "You walk to a hole in the ground stopping you from moving any further"
                        print "the hole seems to be filled with snakes so you cant go through it."
                        print "you are forced to leave the maze."

                    elif turn4 == "leave" or "Leave":
                        print "you leave the maze and return home."

                    else:
                         print "you walk into a wall and go into an irreversable coma"

                elif turn3 == "Left" or "left":
                    print "You walk to a hole in the ground stopping you from moving any further"
                    print "the hole seems to be filled with snakes so you cant go through it."
                    print "you are forced to leave the maze."
                    print "you leave the maze and return home."

                else:
                    print "you walk into a wall and go into an irreversable coma"

            elif turn2 == "Left" or "left":
                print "you turn Left into the maze when you come by a strange man laying on the ground."
                man == raw_input("What do you do? (Help, keep going)")

                if man == "Help" or "help":
                    print "you help the man up and he knocks you out cold"
                    print "you wake back up in your bed at home"

                elif man == "keep going" or "Keep going":
                    print "You leave the man behing after stealing his wallet."
                    print "YOU HAVE REACHED THE END OF THE MAZE"
                    print "You realize the noise was the sound of a old farmer milking a cow."
                    print "The farmer nags at you for coming on private property."

                else:
                    print "you walk into a wall and go into an irreversable coma"

            elif turn2 == "leave" or "Leave":
                print "you leave the maze and return home."

            else:
                print "you walk into a wall and go into an irreversable coma"

        elif turn == "Forward" or "forward":
            print "you move forward into the maze when you come by a strange man laying on the ground."
            man == raw_input("What do you do? (Help, keep going)")

            if man == "Help" or "help":
                    print "you help the man up and he knocks you out cold"
                    print "you wake back up in your bed at home"

            elif man == "keep going" or "Keep going":
                    print "You leave the man behing after stealing his wallet."
                    print "YOU HAVE REACHED THE END OF THE MAZE"
                    print "You realize the noise was the sound of a old farmer milking a cow."
                    print "The farmer nags at you for coming on private property."

            elif turn == "leave" or "Leave":
                    print "you leave the maze and return home."

            else:
                print "you walk into a wall and go into an irreversable coma"

        elif turn == "Right" or "right":
            print "After you turn right you come into a left turn only path."
            print "You turn left and you come to a crossroad."
            turn = raw_input("Which way do you go? (Left, Right, Leave)")

            if turn == "Right" or "right":
                print "You come to a dead end and are forced to turn around"
                turn = raw_input("Which way do you go? (Forward, Leave)")

                if turn == "Forward" or "forward":
                    print "You walk to a hole in the ground stopping you from moving any further"
                    print "the hole seems to be filled with snakes so you cant go through it."
                    print "you are forced to leave the maze."

                else:
                    print "you walk into a wall and go into an irreversable coma"

            elif turn == "Forward" or "forward":
                print "You walk to a hole in the ground stopping you from moving any further"
                print "the hole seems to be filled with snakes so you cant go through it."
                print "you are forced to leave the maze."

            else:
                print "you walk into a wall and go into an irreversable coma"

        elif turn == "Leave" or "leave":
            print "you leave the maze and return home."

        else:
            print "you walk into a wall and go into an irreversable coma"



    elif Enter == "No" or "no":
        print "You walk on into the depths of the night and are robbed by a couple street thugs."

    else:
        print "you walk into a wall and go into an irreversable coma"






def main():

    Game()

main()
```

when i use this program, no matter what i enter into the python shell, it says the same thing over and over again.. it wont take the raw_input statements into context and put them into the if statements

Comment: wow...that is one hell of an `if` tree. ever consider using a table?

Comment: And *what* does it say?

Comment: for sure you wont get answer for this question..you should SO guideline before post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if Enter == "Yes" or "yes":
```

This is not how `or` works.  This is interpreted as `if (Enter == "Yes") or "yes":`.  In python, non-empty strings are always true, so all of the `if` statements like that will be true.  I would suggest something like

```
if Enter.lower() == "yes":
```

which takes care of all of the upper/lower case combinations.

Comment: thank you, your suggestion helped in a way. i erased all the or's and it works. it has a few bugs but not as much as before

Comment: Writing a program like this is one huge bug.

Comment: @Matthias Agreed.  I would suggest a simple state machine.

Comment: If this is Python3.x, use casefold() instead of lower().

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong here:

```
if Enter == "Yes" or "yes":
```

This condition will always be true. `Enter == "Yes"` is first evaluated. If boolean representation is `False`, the boolean representation of `"yes"` will be considered. `bool("yes")` is always `True`.

Consider doing something like:

```
if Enter in ('Yes', 'yes'):
```

Or:

```
if Enter.lower() == 'yes':
```